# Sql Server Stored Procedure with conditional Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a combobox that sets the value of `@NULLFather' and '@NULLMother`. When the combobox is ticked the `WHERE` clause of stored procedure checks for the values of `@NULLFather' and '@NULLMother` and based on that gives a result. But I can't get it to work. Here is the code. I have also tried the case condition but still no success.

```
USE myStudentDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ManualSearchStudents]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@NullFather int = 1,
@NullMother int = 1

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- Insert statements for procedure here

 SELECT StudentName, FatherName, MotherName
 FROM StudentTable 
 WHERE  IF(NULLFather > 0) THEN FatherName IS NULL 
  AND   IF(NullMother > 0) THEN MotherName IS NULL 
 ORDER BY StudentTable.StudentID DESC 
END
```

Comment: try `WHERE ( @NullFather = 0 OR FatherName IS NULL ) AND ( @NullMother = 0 OR MotherName IS NULL )`

Comment: Tried It Works if value of @NullFather > 0. But When Value is = 0 then it shows no result

Comment: It's far easier to use an ORM like EF and construct such queries using LINQ. You *won't* get any performance benefits with "optional parameters" because SQL Server caches the execution plan from the first execution, based on *that* execution's parameters.

Comment: I Think you are right. Using entity framework seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a different solution:

First call the stored procedure and save it to a dataTable . Generate the sql statement string from the combobox. Apply the new sql string to the dataTable. Problem solved. Applied this and it works great. Here is the code:

```
    private DataTable StudentDataExtract()
   {          
         DataTable ds = new DataTable();

        try
        {


            string sqlSelect = "SearchStudents";
            EntityConnection scontext = new EntityConnection();
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(scontext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, c); //c.con is the connection string
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            c.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            da.Fill(ds);

            c.Close();

            if (GetFilter != "")
            {
                ds = ManualFilter(ds);
            }
            else
            {
                string dataOrder = "SID DESC";
                DataView dv = ds.DefaultView;
                dv.Sort = dataOrder;
                ds = dv.ToTable();
            }

            return ds;

        }
        catch (SqlException e)

        {
            return ds;
        }
    }


    private DataTable ManualFilter(DataTable OldDataTable)
    {
        DataTable NewDataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            NewDataTable = OldDataTable.Select(GetFilter, dataOrder).CopyToDataTable();
            return NewDataTable;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return NewDataTable;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return NewDataTable;
        }
    }

    private string getfilter = "";
    public string GetFilter
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerable<String> selectedData = combolist.Where(d => d.IsSelected).Select(d => d.myTableValue);
            string singleString = string.Join(" OR ", selectedData.ToArray());
            return singleString;
        }
        set
        {
            getfilter = value; OnPropertyChanged("GetFilter"); OnPropertyChanged("GetStudentData");
        }

    }




    public DataTable GetStudentData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.StudentDataExtract();
        }

    }


   public class ComboSet : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set { isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); OnPropertyChanged("GetFilter"); }
        }

        private string mydataproperty;

        public string myDataProperty
        {
            get { return mydataproperty; }
            set { mydataproperty = value; }
        }

        private string mytablevalue;

        public string myTableValue
        {
            get { return mytablevalue; }
            set { mytablevalue = value; }
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<ComboSet> combolist;

    public ObservableCollection<ComboSet> ComboList
    {
        get { return combolist; }
        set { combolist = value; }
    }
```